# GAS MailApp.SendEmail - include multiple attachments using ss cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have file names separated by commas (no spaces) in a google sheets cell 'filez1.pdf,filez2.pdf'.

If I assign a variable as a string;

flist = "filez1.pdf,filez2.pdf"

or an array

flist = ["filez1.pdf", "filez2.pdf"]

I cannot send multiple files as below.

I have tried numerous syntax for **XXXX** e.g. flist[], [flist], flist[0]

*

> MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject ,message, {attachments:
>   **XXXX**});

*

and keep getting the same error *'Invalid argument: attachments
    at SendMail(SendEmail:15)'*

This works but I don't know how to address multiple files;

> var flist = DriveApp.getFilesByName('filez1')
>
> MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject ,message, {attachments:
>
> flist.next().getBlob()});

Any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome. The Google documentation has a specific example for [sending multiple attachments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)). In addition, you might read [Send an email with attachment using Google Apps Script [duplicate]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60445/196152) or its predecessor [Send email with an attachment located in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79324/196152).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email with an attachment located in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79324/send-email-with-an-attachment-located-in-google-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Since no other answer was found anywhere I pursued the problem till I found something that works for me.

```
function SendMail() {
     var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
     spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SheetName'), true);
     var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();  
     var subject = spreadsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
     var emailAddress = spreadsheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
     var message = spreadsheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
     var filesarray = []
     var files = []
     var startRow = 1;
     var lastRow = spreadsheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length;

       for (var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i++)
       {    filesarray[i-3] = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(); //load column values, file names, into filesarray
       }

       for (var i = 0; i <= lastRow-3; i++)

       {var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filesarray[i]); // assign gdrive name to new array files
  while(file.hasNext()){var tfly=file.next();}
  files.push(tfly)
       }

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject ,message, {attachments: files});

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Back to calling sheet'), true);
}
```